# How do I create a nested dictonary from a specific file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary, nested

I have a CSV file with rows ordered like this. [image: CSV Image]

Table in text

| 0 | EST | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:00AM |  | Starting |  |
| 2 | 7:00PM | Prayer |  | Game Night |
| 3 | 8:00PM | Board game | Ask anything |  |

I'm trying to create a nested Dictionary so that when someone asks for a Day (eg: Monday), all the events happening that day together with the time would be produced.

```
my_dict = {'Monday':{'EST':'7:30: PM', 'Event': 'Prayer Meeting', 'EST':'8:00: PM', 'Event': 'Board Game',}}
```

If a nested dictonary is not the right way, please guide me.

Comment: please share you data as text

Comment: Noted. I'll do that.

Comment: @Pablo C it's been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when someone asks for a Day (eg: Monday), all the events happening that day together with the time would be produced.

I think then dictionary should looks different:

First use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot and then remove rows with missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), last use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in dict comprehension and create nested dictionaries:

```
df1 = df.melt('EST').dropna(subset=['value'])

d = {k: dict(zip(v['EST'], v['value'])) for k, v in df1.groupby('variable')}
print (d)
{'Monday': {'7:00PM': 'Prayer', '8:00PM': 'Board game'},
 'Tuesday': {'12:00AM': 'Starting', '8:00PM': 'Ask anything'},
 'Wednesday': {'7:00PM': 'Game Night'}}
```

Another alternative with different ouput - for each day are create lists of dictionaries - in dict comprehension is used [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('EST', value_name='event').dropna(subset=['event'])

d = {k: v[['EST','event']].to_dict(orient='records') for k, v in df1.groupby('variable')}
print (d)
{'Monday': [{'EST': '7:00PM', 'event': 'Prayer'}, 
            {'EST': '8:00PM', 'event': 'Board game'}], 
 'Tuesday': [{'EST': '12:00AM', 'event': 'Starting'}, 
             {'EST': '8:00PM', 'event': 'Ask anything'}], 
 'Wednesday': [{'EST': '7:00PM', 'event': 'Game Night'}]}
```

Comment: How do you think it should look? I'm new to all this and any advice or opinion would help me.

Comment: @Dave - Sure, I only change dict for key for times and values for events

Comment: Yes, this solution works. Thank you. I'll like some explanation though. Or if you can link me to the appropriate documentation.

Comment: @Dave - Sure, give me a sec.